# Null reference exception in c# when am running the following code

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I am just a learner.I am getting null reference exception for the following snippet.Please correct the mistake and tell me what's wrong with this code.

```
  class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Company objcompany = new Company();

            Employee obj1 = new Employee(101, "Test1");
            Employee obj2=  new Employee(102, "Test2");
            Employee obj3 = new Employee(103, "Test3");

            objcompany.EmpList.Add(obj1);
            objcompany.EmpList.Add(obj2);
            objcompany.EmpList.Add(obj3);

            foreach (var emp in objcompany.EmpList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(emp.EmpId + " " + emp.EmpName);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class Company
    {
        public List<Employee> EmpList { get; set; }
    }

    class Employee
    {
        public int EmpId { get; set; }
        public string EmpName { get; set; }

        public Employee(int empid, String empname)
        {
            this.EmpId = empid;
            this.EmpName = empname;
        }
    }
```

i have created 3 classes.[Employee,Company,Program].I want to add employees into the collection.I am processing the code in the program class.

Comment: Which line of code is throwing the null reference exception?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a substitute for debugging your code.

Comment: you must initialize list before start adding item to it

Comment: Jonathon Reinhart - I don't ask you to debug this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not initialized `EmpList`. I would suggest you to initialize it in *Company* class constructor

```
class Company
{
    public Company()
    {
         EmpList = new List<Employee>();
    }
    public List<Employee> EmpList { get; set; }
}
```